# How to change root/path of public folder in wamp server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

i'm using laravel and i want to change (assets) folder path from public to another path
[image]

(assets) folder contains CSS and JS files

when cut it in another path the css and js files does not load, how to make wamp server knows the new path?

i need help

Comment: Browser should have access to js and css files. so if you exit them from public folder, they will not be accessible in laravel.

Comment: @ArashYounesi please explain more

Comment: When you run a laravel application, the first file is index.php in public folder. means any there is no direct access to another folders by browser. so you should put all compiled css and js files in the `public` folder.

Comment: i tried to use xamp server and it works fine, i think the problem in wamp server

Comment: i took out index.php  and .htaccess  from public path and removed public path from the code in addition removed public path from server.php

Comment: Yes, by editing server.php you can handle that. but for your case it is not a good work, because you can run for examples controllers directly from browser by addressing them that is a crtical security issue

Answer (score 0):

put all the files from public to root folder (e.g .htacess and other files) make folder folder and use as asset

Comment: i already did it cut (.htaccess and index.php) but stilling does not know the new path